# How to create EditText in Android from java file

Tags: android

How to make EditText in Android to take only numeric input from Java file not from XML ? 
Also i need to make it a PASSWORD field  which allows a max of 6 numers ?

I checked [Android: How do you create an EditText feild in java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857232/android-how-do-you-create-an-edittext-feild-in-java-class)

and  [How to create EditText numeric (signed and unsigned decimal) from java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302304/how-to-create-edittext-numeric-signed-and-unsigned-decimal-from-java-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy from XML.
This is how we can do this java file.

```
EditText et = new EditText(context);                     
// setting input type filter        
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);                    
// setting input max length
InputFilter maxLengthFilter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(inp.getLength());
et.setFilters((new InputFilter[]{ maxLengthFilter }));
// settin it to password 
et.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setInputType to one or more of these values:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Answer (score 0):

i've done this in `XML`, just add

`android:numeric="decimal`

in the `<EditText />`

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylinearlayout);

Button lButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybtnid);
lButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    EditText lEditText = new EditText(this);
    lEditText .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     lEditText.SetText("Text Here");
     mLinearLayout.addView(lEditText);

EditorInfo ed = new EditorInfo();
ed.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE;                          
lEditText.setInputType(ed.inputType);

InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(6);
lEditText.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

or check this [blog](http://androidblogger.blogspot.pt/2009/01/numeric-edittext-and-edittext-with-max.html) for limit max length

Aditya answer has the method to password, and i think it's better

Best regards